# Disable admin menu items by configuration value Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to disable admin menu when module enable set to `No` in configuration.

I have tried to use `ifconfig="section/group/field"` there but that's not working.
Here is my admin menu code.

`Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::sample" title="Sample" translate="title" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="60" parent="Vendor_Module::sample1" action="sample/sample/index/" resource="Vendor_Module::sample"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

on the `add` tag add an attribute `dependsOnConfig="section/group/field"`

```
<add id="Vendor_Module::sample" 
     title="Sample" translate="title" 
     module="Vendor_Module" 
     sortOrder="60" 
     parent="Vendor_Module::sample1" 
     action="sample/sample/index/" 
     resource="Vendor_Module::sample"
     dependsOnConfig="section/group/field"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius. What kind of scope value will consider by dependsOnConfig to read? Currently, I added store view specific scope to that Enable/Disable field. If I'll change the status from any one store view dependsOnConfig getting false value.